# What does it mean by 'Gaussian distribution at vector x'?

Tags: normal-distribution

> Write a MATLAB function that computes the value of the Gaussian
>   distribution N(m, S), at a given vector x.

What does it mean by 'Gaussian distribution at vector x'?

What does the question want actually?

Comment: The Gaussian distribution is quite literally a function. In the case of a vector random variable, it's a function of a vector. When you evaluate a function at some particular value of its argument, $x$ (here a vector), you evaluate that function "at a vector, $x$"

Answer (score 1):

In this case a vector is an object in MATLAB, an array of numbers. What it says is that you can apply such function in MATLAB to all the indices of such object and evaluate Gaussian distribution function on them. So for each of the elements in your vector `x` it returns their [probability densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) or [cumulative probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) depending on what exactly is the function you describe (it is not clear from the context). It does *not* transform `x` to vector of normally distributed values of the same size.

Comment: still not clear to me.

Comment: That means, I will obtain a new vector of the same size of input vector whose elements are normally distributed.